# Ссылка на "коммерческие" стандарты

Tags: обсуждение, авторские-права

Камарады, я не требую однозначный ответ - нужны просто предложения. Ибо речь идет о ресурсе ruSO и информации, которая ... "продается за денюжку". Пока речь идет о текущих Cтандартах C++.

Да, понимаю, draft (черновики) до поры, до времени, лежат в свободном доступе. В принципе, и линк можно кинуть. Но, как только Cтандарт релизиться, все - он публично недоступен.

**Важно**

По метке `c++` зачастую проходят оживленные баталии. И единственный арбитр, по факту - текущий Cтандарт. Аргументируя свой ответ, по-любому, на Стандарт ссылаться как-то надо.

**... А как?**

Скромное, хотя и наглое, предположение - попросить админов стековерфлова официально купить право на получение текущего Стандарта, и с правом его частичного цитирования. Хотя, понимаю, это - из области [корчевателя](https://lurkmore.to/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C). Практически - анрил.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [В: Где взять стандарт C++?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417797/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82-c?s=1|2.8209)

Comment: @Nick Volynkin , все верно. Но по ссылке лишь расшифровка деталей. Но решения так и нет.

Answer (score 2):

> все - он публично недоступен

Черновик остаётся доступен даже после утверждения Стандарта. Так что ссылать на него по-прежнему можно. Изменения между последней публичной версией черновика и утвержденного Стандарта минимальны. Если по какой-то причине возникнет ситуация, когда изменение существенно для обсуждаемого вопроса, то не сомневаюсь, что обладатель Стандарта сможет, если и не прямой цитатой (из-за потенциальных юридических нюансов), то хотя бы своими словами рассказать о наличии такого изменения. Если кто-то не готов верить таким словам, что ж, пускает покупает Стандарт и убеждается в этом лично.

> купить право на получение текущего Стандарта, и с правом его частичного цитирования.

Сомневаюсь, что такое возможно, т.к. не могу представить, как можно, купив одну копию Стандарта, предоставить её в одновременное пользование всем участникам SO. Если доступ будет открытым для всех - никто другой покупать Стандарт не будет.

Таким образом, озвученная Вами проблема мне кажется надуманной.

Comment: Скорее не проблема надуманна - решение надумано. Тут соглашусь, я ни разу не юрист.

Comment: Значит надо как-то отслеживать последний draft, возможно для него "закрепить" тему.

Comment: @Majestio он отслеживается, в частности, в упомянутой Ником теме.

Comment: Норм. Только смущают даты - апрель 2016. Или там бамбук курят, или актуализация хромает.

Comment: @Majestio на https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard сейчас от 28 ноября версия доступна. Но можно и с гита взять посвежее.

Comment: благодарю!! А на гите - последний "черновик" актуализируется? И если не затруднит, можно линк в туда?

Comment: @Majestio собственно там он и создаётся. Ссылка там же жирными буквами **github**.